# How do I run existing nginx repo on windows or ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I am a freelance front-end developer, just enough PHP, Apache and Unix to get by. **ZERO NGINX**. To work on this client's site I need to work with this repo (file tree below).

I've researched enough to:

- Install nginx and know that I can point my nginx to the configuration file in this repo.
  **But** I get user errors `(nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("system") failed)` then `nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "dav_ext_methods"` and I'm just going down a rabbit hole.
- I've also tried nginx on Laragon and tried to modify the Laragon nginx templates to no avail.
- I've installed nginx on WSL but there is far to much configuration to learn to make this work on time.
- I have also installed CLion to try and use its environment configuration (CMakeLists.txt) but again, not familiar at all with that IDE. Made me install cygwin, CMake and a bunch of other stuff... another time sucking rabbit hole.

**I need help!!**

I am hoping that someone can look a the contents of this repo and give me some steps to follow.

```
webapp
|   .gitignore
|   CMakeLists.txt
|   php-fpm.conf
|
+---.git
|
+---html
|
+---init
|       nginx.service
|
+---nginx_cfg
|       fastcgi_params
|       mime.types
|       naxsi.rules
|       naxsi_core.rules
|       nginx.conf
|       nginx_user_cert.conf
|       scgi_params
|
+---php-fpm.d
|       www.conf
|
\---themes
```

Comment: Hi, grep dav_ext_methods in +---nginx_cfg directory think the webdav Module is missing